# bash: export not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, bashrc, environment

I was changing the  bashrc file based upon the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ipd8vkAj8Fk&t=182s but suddenly when I type `sudo su` I get the following error

```
bash: export: `/home/mala/WRFinstall/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich/bin:/home/mala/WRFinstall/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games': not a valid identifier
```

I tried to edit the bashrc file by typing `nano ~/.bashrc`  but I can't find the file I edited. I only get content of a normal bash file.

Comment: Could you add the content of the video you followed, the commands you ran at least?

Comment: Why did you edit your .bashrc? Please give more information. If it is _your_ .bashrc, why do you have to use sudo? Does the error also occur when you run `source ~/.bashrc`? Or did you by accident modify `root`'s .bashrc? Test this by running `sudo cat /root/.bashrc`.  From the error message, it seems that should read `export PATH=...`, but you missed the identifier "PATH".

Comment: It appears you edited this ` /etc/bash.bashrc ` file please check that

Comment: Thank you @ridgy .I accidentally modified the root bashrc  .when i typed 'sudo cat /root/.bashrc' i found the content i modified .I had followded the previous video and this link http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php

 `#WRF environment variables
export DIR=/home/mala/WRFinstall/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
export FC=gfortran
export CFLAGS=-m64
export F77=gfortran
export FFLAGS=-m64
export PATH=$DIR/netcdf/bin:$PATH
export NETCDF=$DIR/netcdf
export PATH= $DIR/mpich/bin:$PATH`

How can i change it?

Comment: As you are using `nano`, just run `sudo nano /root/.bashrc` and remove the accidentially added lines. The error is the blank after `PATH=`; there must be no whitespace there (see the other `export`statements).

Comment: Thanak you @ridgy . It solved my problem

Comment: @ridgy post that as a proper answer instead of comment

Comment: @MalaPokhrel Please add the text file content into your post. It's impossible to read in a comment.